# Scala version 2.11 - missing libraries

Tags: scala, import, version, libraries

I am trying to work in some projects that I have made using Scala 2.10, now I am using Scala 2.11. I am getting this error:

```
IO error while decoding C:\...\eclipse\Workspace\Project...\src\...with UTF-8 Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
```

I am getting the libraries which are mentioned: Swing, Continuations...and also scala-all, but non of them doesn't fix that. Any idea which can be the problem? Thanks

### Edit:

I had some `Map`s and the error was standing until I imported `scala.collection.mutable.Map` !

Answer (score 1):

Try these flags for the source code, when compiling:

"-encoding" "UTF-8"

I use these flags in SBT:

```
lazy val javaMajorVersion  = "1.8"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild  := "2.11.4",

scalacOptions in ThisBuild := Seq(
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  s"-target:jvm-$javaMajorVersion",
  "-deprecation",
  "-feature",
  "-unchecked",
  "-Xlint")
```

Comment: actually I have switched to Eclipse IDE. What you think that I can apply there?

Comment: the SBT eclipse plugin. Try this project i wrote, it might help you get all set up. https://github.com/fractal/skeleton